# Websocket closing issue

Tags: websocket

I am working on web application for client side which is user websocket connection to send/receive data.
Here is my problem.

If some parameter change on client side, I want to close my web socket connection and initiate new connection with new paramaeters.
I tried to close web socket connection bu using close(). But when I checked my browser console, websocket status is always 2. 
Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure of what problem you have, but if you set a handler for `onclose`, it will be triggered when you call `close`.

```
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://wss://echo.websocket.org');
ws.onclose=function(){
    alert('The websocket just closed, readyState: ' + ws.readyState);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6kh20bdy/

ReadyState 3 means closed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#Constants